# A complicated integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to do this complicated integral:

[image]

And my code is as follows:

```
f[k_] := 
 k^3 (ln[1 + 2.34 k]/(2.34 k))^2 (1 + 
    3.89 k + (16.1 k)^2 + (5.46 k)^3 + (6.71 k)^4)^-0.5 (3 Sin[k*R]/(k*R)^3 - 3 Cos[k*R]/(k*R)^2)^2

NIntegrate[f[k], {k, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {R > 0}]
```

But I can't get an answer and what I would like to do in the end is to draw a figure about F(R).

Could you please help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) Some basic syntax: `Sin` not `sin`, `Cos` not `cos`, etc. (2) Decimal points in numbers represent approximate floating point numbers. It's best to use exact numbers (e.g. rational fractions) in exact solvers like `Integrate`. (Round-off error sometimes messes up exact computations.) (3) Some integrals are too hard for Mathematica or any other system to solve symbolically. Would a numerical approach work for you? It might be an easier to plot a graph.

Comment: Some advice for people learning Mma: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999

Comment: Forgot this tip: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I try to use NIntegrate and replace every floating point number into integers but still can not get a result, could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

[Another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) to [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) explains the use of `_?NumericQ` and has links to similar Q&A as this one.

```
f[k_, R_] := (* tip: avoid initial capitals (use r not R) *)
 k^3 (Log[1 + 2.34 k]/(2.34 k))^2 (1 + 
     3.89 k + (16.1 k)^2 + (5.46 k)^3 + (6.71 k)^4)^-0.5 (3 Sin[
        k*R]/(k*R)^3 - 3 Cos[k*R]/(k*R)^2)^2;

ff[r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[k, r], {k, 0, Infinity}];

Plot[ff[R], {R, 1/10, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm is written "Log". Further, "NIntegrate" can only do numerical integrals. Therefore, you must replace "R" by a number ("DSolve" take a long time.):

```
f[k_] := 
 k^3 (Log[1 + 2.34 k]/(2.34 k))^2 (1 + 
     3.89 k + (16.1 k)^2 + (5.46 k)^3 + (6.71 k)^4)^-0.5 (3 Sin[
        k*R]/(k*R)^3 - 3 Cos[k*R]/(k*R)^2)^2
d = Table[{R, NIntegrate[f[k], {k, 0, Infinity}]}, {R, 0.1, 10, 
    0.1}];
ListLinePlot[d, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]